# Proposing tag wiki creation does not work on meta sites

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, per-site-meta

Try creating a tag wiki on any meta site except for this one, e.g. http://meta.superuser.com/tags/etiquette/info. The "Propose Tag Wiki" button does nothing.

[image: Broken propose button]

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/611/allow-editing-of-site-specific-tag-wikis-in-meta

Answer (score 18):

Works now, you can edit any wikis on per-site metas, including the ones sourced from this meta.

The thing is, our little meta here is a funny place, sometimes the tag wikis we float to the child metas do not properly fit the community.

The community now have full control around evolving tag wikis on site metas.

Comment: What happens if there's a change on a child meta to [meta-tag:discussion] say and then a change is also made here? Does the change made here get pushed and overwrite the child meta change or do the tag wikis stay divergent (and possibly wrong).

Answer (score 14):

The current state of this situation is ... unsatisfying.

Here is a screenshot from Cryptography Stack Exchange's meta:

[image: screenshot from crypto.SE]

We got a lot of tags auto-created when the site started, but most of them have no tag wikis (= guidance for users on how to use them). The tag wiki excerpts for the mandatory and some moderator-only tags are there, but no other one.

I can understand that SE.Inc wants to have consistent meta tagging between all sites, but then:

- You should really copy the tag-wikis for the auto-generated tags, not just say *we plan to push out the shared meta tag wikis from meta.so* (this plan is at least seven months old).
- You should not have "create tag wiki", "edit tag wiki" or "propose tag wiki" buttons (and the gray text saying that one can create a wiki) when they don't do anything. (There is not even a message saying that it is not possible now.)

Also, many per-site metas have unique tags which are not shared with meta.SO (or should not have a shared tag wiki, as they mean something else here).
Please allow editing at least those ones (like maybe our [mathjax] tag, or the [[qotw] tag on security.SE](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qotw)).

**How could this look like?**

- For tag which are shared with meta.SO (and auto-created by the system), have a sentence on the wiki page like "this tag wiki is shared with meta.stackoverflow", with a link to the tag wiki page there (instead of the edit/create/propose button).
- For tags which are not shared (i.e. created locally), enable editing normally, as on normal sites. (Alternatively you could forbid creating new tags, but I don't think this is the right way to do it.)

Comment: For example, I would like to have a tag wiki (excerpt) explaining the difference between [scope] and [allowed-questions].

Comment: [meta-tag:allowed-questions] doesn't even exist on MSO! There's [meta-tag:allowed-topics], which is a synonym of [meta-tag:scope]. The set of automatically imported tags could use a dust-off.

Answer (score 5):

#### [Please allow editing tag wikis on child metas](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/please-allow-editing-tags-on-child-metas)

I posted on [Meta French Language & Usage](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/please-allow-editing-tags-on-child-metas):

> - The set of copied tags is pretty small, leading to quite a bit of divergence. (What's the tag for discussing the topic delineation of a site? `scope`? `off-topic`? `on-topic`? `allowed-topics`? `on-topic-discussion`? `off-topic-discussion`? `on-topic-definition`? `off-topic-content`? `on-off-topic`? `on-topic-off-topic`? All of these exist on some meta, many metas use more than one, and that's not all of them.)
> - There are issues that are unique to specific metas. For example, [language](/questions/tagged/language) is the #2 tag here, for an issue that doesn't exist on most sites.
> - Some metas have specific needs. For example, it would be nice to have French translations of tag wikis on Meta too.
>
> Please allow child metas to have their own tag wikis. Ideally, any tag on a child meta should automatically have its MSO tag wiki unless locally overridden. In other words, allow tag wiki edition on child metas, and show the MSO tag wiki if the local tag wiki is empty.

*And I swear I'd totally forgotten about [Paŭlo Ebermann's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109419/149076) until he reminded me in chat. Yet I came up with pretty much the same request.*

Answer (score 2):

This should be addressed as soon as possible.

I'm getting all sorts of signals telling me I can and should create a tag wiki when I actually can't. Reloading the page immediately after clicking a dummy button doesn't give any indication to the user what's wrong. It's especially unclear if the error was caused by the site or my browser. Only by finding this question did I discover it was by design.