# There is a UI bug when trying to edit meta tag wikis

Tags: bug, edits, user-interface, meta, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proposing tag wiki creation does not work on meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92219/proposing-tag-wiki-creation-does-not-work-on-meta-sites)

When I try to edit a tag wiki on a meta site I cannot, rather I get what seems to be an error message ***which doesn't reflect reality***:

> There is no tag wiki for this tag … yet!
>
> Tag wikis help introduce newcomers to the tag. They contain an overview of the topic defined by the tag, along with guidelines on its usage.
>
> ***All registered users may propose new tag wikis.*** <sup>(emphasis mine. this text is the bug, not the inability to edit the tag but the UI lying about it)</sup>
>
> (Note that if you have less than 4000 reputation, your tag wiki will be peer reviewed before it is published.)

Since I do have greater than 4000 rep, there are a couple of problems:

- All registered users may ***not*** propose new tags for the ***meta*** site.
- ***4000 reputation*** is only a factor for the main site, not the meta site.
- ***Peer review*** doesn't even have a chance to happen for the meta site.

Instead there should be either:

- Separate messages for the case of trying to edit with insufficient rep vs trying to edit on meta.
- A longer message with covers both.
- Umm maybe like err having some degree of rep which actually does permit us to give tag wikis to new tags that we were umm permitted to create (-:

***UPDATE***

It seems some people aren't reading this bug report and think I'm complaining about not being able to edit the meta tag wiki, which is by design. Not so. I'm complaining that the UI wrongly declares that we *can* edit it instead of saying we can't edit it because it's designed that way.

Comment: When you say 'edit a tag' do you just mean 'edit a tag wiki'?

Comment: Or: you were erroneously denied to propose the tag wiki?

Comment: @LanceRoberts: I don't know what it might be called technially within SE as I would've been taken to the page where both the tag wiki and the tag wiki excerpt could be edited and/or suggested. The two ways I tried were by clicking on "help us edit this wiki" in the popup that appears when hovering over a tag, and the "Create Tag Wiki" button on the "Tag Info" page.

Comment: @Arjan: Yes that could also be a possibility! But I thought I read once that we can't edit the tag wikis on meta tags so I wasn't thinking about that option and only considered that the interface was at fault.

Comment: ok, edited to reflect that, so there's no confusion with creating/editing the actual tag itself.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Ah yes I wasn't sure what you were getting at but I've been able to create new blank tags on the same meta site for some time.

Comment: That possible duplicate states it doesn't work *"on any meta site except for this one"*. On which Meta did you get this error message?

Comment: I got this on meta.travel but I'm sure I've had it elsewhere, it doesn't look any different whether you've reached 4k or not.

Comment: The other question is specifically about what happens with **less than** 4k rep.